# Problemas al iniciar la consola de mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que no puedo iniciar mongodb, estoy en linux mas
específicamente en deepin os, y cuando en la terminal escribo `mongo` me sale este error:

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

¿Alguien me puede decir porqué pasa esto y cómo arreglarlo? Desde ya gracias

### Edit

Al hacer lo que dijo un comentario, escribir en la consola `sudo systemctl status mongod` obetengo este mensaje:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual

dic 09 12:56:06 davebook-Linux systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service:11: PIDFile= references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /
dic 09 12:56:25 davebook-Linux systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service:11: PIDFile= references path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /
lines 1-7/7 (END)
```

Y si es que intento iniciarlo no da error ni nada por el estilo, pero después de intentar iniciarlo al ver el status obtengo este otro mensaje:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-12-09 12:58:01 CST; 5s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 19259 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
 Main PID: 19259 (code=exited, status=14)

dic 09 12:58:01 davebook-Linux systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
dic 09 12:58:01 davebook-Linux systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
dic 09 12:58:01 davebook-Linux systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: y mongo esta escuchando en ese puerto?

Comment: @gbianchi creo que tampoco se inicia mongodb, o al menos cuando veo los puertos en uso no esta nada relacionado a mongodb

Comment: ¿Sabes si el demonio de MongoDB está activo? No conozco a fondo esa distribución de Linux, parece basada en Debian, por lo que he podido averiguar. Si utiliza `systemd`, verifica que el servicio de MongoDB está activo mediante `sudo systemctl status mongod`. Comenta el resultado.

Comment: @MauricioContreras listo, añadí lo que dijiste y un poco más de información

Comment: Verifica el contenido del archivo `/etc/mongod.conf`. Uno de los errores más comunes que evitan el inicio correcto del servicio de MongoDB es que la ruta de almacenamiento de la base de datos no está accesible, la misma se establece en el valor [`storage.dbPath`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-storage.dbPath). Debes asegurarte que dicha ruta exista. Prueba eso en principio.

Comment: @MauricioContreras lo siento si la pregunta es básica, pero soy completamente nuevo en mongodb, mi pregunta es ¿el storage.dbPath debe estar en el direcotrio  `/`, junto a carpetas como etc, var, y otras? o en que parte debe de estart

Comment: Puedes ver el contenido del archivo de configuración escribiendo en la consola: `cat /etc/mongodb.conf`. En dicho archivo se guarda la configuración de inicio del servicio de mongodb. Revisa el valor `dbPath` del registro llamado `storage`, puedes ver [esta imagen](https://imgur.com/a/U8NPXCZ) de muestra de un archivo `mongodb.conf` típico. Allí puedes apreciar el valor de `storage:  dbPath:`. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras listo ya revise la ruta, y si existe ya que si abro esa ruta me muestra varios archivos, ¿qué otra cosa puede evitar el inicio de mongodb?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132212/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-david-flores-garcia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema al parecer estaba en el dueño de la carpeta `/var/lib/mongodb`, ya que como me comentó Mauricio Contreras en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132212/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-david-flores-garcia) si escribia el comando `sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb` ya debería de tener permisos el usuario de mongodb para acceder ahí, por lo que una vez hecho eso hice un `sudo systemctl restart mongod` y al ver el status de mongodb ya esta corriendo y ya puedo acceder a la consola sin problemas.